# Do fixtures work with response.context in Django unit tests?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

It's my first time writing tests for Django. So far I've used a fixture which contains test data and checked that my database model methods generate the correct outputs. So far so good. I'm now trying to test my views by checking that my context variable contain what they should. But I get a NoneType error as below. I've tried all I can, maybe fixtures don't work with self.client.get() and response.context() ?

```
C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2>c:/Users/Philip/CodeRepos/Acacia2/venv/Scripts/activate.bat

(venv) C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2>python manage.py test journal
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py:1361: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Ledger.last_spreadsheet_update received a naive datetime (1970-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py:1361: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField JournalEntry.last_integrity_check received a naive datetime (1970-01-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  warnings.warn("DateTimeField %s received a naive datetime (%s)"
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\venv\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\base.py:116: UserWarning: No directory at: C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\staticfiles\
  warnings.warn(u"No directory at: {}".format(root))
E.........
======================================================================
ERROR: test (journal.tests.Balances)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2\journal\tests.py", line 48, in test
    response.context['coa_groups'],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 10 tests in 0.223s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

(venv) C:\Users\Philip\CodeRepos\Acacia2>
```

urls.py

```
path('ledgers/show/all', views.ledgers_show_all, name='ledgers_show_all'),
```

Views.py

```
@login_required
def ledgers_show_all(request):  

    coa_groups = COAGroup.objects.all()
    total_profit_loss = 0
    for coa_group in coa_groups:
        coa_group.balance2 = 0
        coa_group.coa_sub_groups_with_balances = []            
        for coa_sub_group in coa_group.coasubgroup_set.all():
            coa_sub_group.ledgers_with_balances = []
            coa_sub_group.balance2 = 0
            coa_sub_group.display = False
            for ledger in coa_sub_group.ledger_set.all():
                ledger.balance2 = ledger.balance
                if ledger.balance2 != 0 or ledger.status != '1':
                    coa_sub_group.display = True
                coa_sub_group.balance2 += ledger.balance2
                coa_sub_group.ledgers_with_balances.append(ledger)
            coa_group.balance2 += coa_sub_group.balance2
            coa_group.coa_sub_groups_with_balances.append(coa_sub_group)
        total_profit_loss += coa_group.balance2
    return render(request, 'journal/ledgers_show_all.html',{'coa_groups': coa_groups})
```

Tests.py

```
class Balances(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['db.json', ]

    def test(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('journal:ledgers_show_all'))
        self.assertEqual(
            response.context['coa_groups'],
            1 # Just a test value for now
        )
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace for the error. Fixtures do work in tests - so there is likely some other issue which a stack trace would throw light on.

Comment: @solarissmoke I've added full response.

Comment: What template backend are you using? The only way I can see `response.context` being `None` is if you're not using Django's default backend, and are using Jinja2 or something instead.

Comment: Hi. I printed the response.context and it shows a redirect to my login page! So looks like I need to add some auto login to get the context.

Comment: Ah, I had missed the `login_required` decorator. You're looking for [force_login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login).